# angular2 mydatepicker does not work properly

Tags: angular

I am using angular 2 mydatepicker.

I need default selected value.

here is my code

```
import {IMyOptions,IMyDateModel} from 'mydatepicker';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators ,FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

export class CommentsPage {
Addevent;
private myDatePickerOptions: IMyOptions = {
  dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
};
constructor() {
  let date = new Date();
  this.Addevent.controls['EVENT_DATE'].setValue({
    date: {
         year: date.getFullYear(),
         month: date.getMonth() + 1,
         day: date.getDate()}
  });
}

ngOnInit() 
    {

      this.Addevent = this.formbuilder.group({
       EVENT_DATE:[''],
      }); 
    } 
}
```

here is my Html code

```
<form [formGroup]="Addevent" (ngSubmit)="add(Addevent.value)" novalidate>
       <div>    
        <h5 class="d1">DATE</h5>
        <my-date-picker name="mydate" [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
                   formControlName="EVENT_DATE"></my-date-picker>
        </div>  
 </form>
```

But i am getting this err

```
Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'EVENT_DATE'
```

How can i fix this issue.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it. But from the error, this might help you by making FormControl Instance to `Addevent`.

```js
import {IMyOptions,IMyDateModel} from 'mydatepicker';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators ,FormControl} from '@angular/forms';


export class CommentsPage {
Addevent: FormGroup;
private myDatePickerOptions: IMyOptions = {
  dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
};
constructor(private formbuilder: FormBuilder) {
  let date = new Date();
  this.Addevent.controls['EVENT_DATE'].setValue({
    date: {
         year: date.getFullYear(),
         month: date.getMonth() + 1,
         day: date.getDate()}
  });
}

ngOnInit() 
    {

      this.Addevent = this.formbuilder.group({
       EVENT_DATE:[''],
      }); 
    } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```